# IS IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0.0.00 supports indexedDB

Tags: cordova, indexeddb, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement indexedDB in my mobile app.here i am giving my code

```
function readAll() {
    var objectStore = db.transaction("customers").objectStore("customers");

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
      var cursor = event.target.result;
      if (cursor) {
            alert("Name for id " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + ", Age: " + cursor.value.age + ", Email: " + cursor.value.email);
            cursor.continue();
      }
      else {
            alert("No more entries!");
      }
    };     
}
```

in this cursor.continue(); shows with red line in my js file.I don't know why

Please any one help.I got this code from

http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/12/23/html5-storage-indexeddb/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst does not provide IndexedDB support as this is not a feature that it *can* provide.

MobileFirst uses Cordova at its base. If Cordova supports IndexedDB, your application will be able to use it.

According to [the Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/storage/storage.html), IndexedDB is supported in:

- BlackBerry 10
- Firefox OS
- Windows Phone 8
- Windows 8

Comment: It's supported on iOS too if you use the WKWebView, that can be done right now using the WKWebView plugin

Comment: MobileFirst embdes Cordova 3.7 and as such does not support WKWebView.

Comment: It supports cordova plugins, right? there is a WKWebView plugin from telerik that is supported by cordova 3.x.x

Comment: If that plug-in requires installation using Cordova plug-man then unfortunately that will not work either. :/

Comment: it can be installed from cordova CLI, plugman, etc, like any other plugin

Comment: The application referred here was not created by the Cordova CLI. It is generated by tools that do not provide the ability to use external tools to modify it. This was fixed in MovilfeFirst 7.1 that is now able to create "pure" Cordova apps which will allow such plug-in installation.

Comment: But even if you can't install plugins from the CLI, you can create plugins and install them manually, right? this tutorial for mobile first 7.0 explains how to create a cordova ios plugin for mobile first https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/ios-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/. The only reason I can think for wkwebview not working is that it requires the webserver plugin and maybe IBM blocks this kind of plugins for security reason

Comment: Yes, you could take an existing plugin and follow instructions to re-create it with some tweaks by following said tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

please go through below link cordova supports

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/support/index.html

Comment: MobileFirst embeds Cordova 3.7, so this is will not help.